# Turning a plain text string into a table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm scratching my head around this javascript exercise:
I receive this plain text using Ajax:

```js
“201 George /  / ”
“301 Mary / 302 Lucy / ”
“401 Craig Da / 402 Ann / 403 Al Mia”
```

I need to create 3 objects like this:

```
{
    "floor2": [{
        "apart": "201",
        "name": "George"

    }],
    "floor3": [{
        "apart": "301",
        "name": "Mary"
    }, {
        "apart": "302",
        "name": "Lucy"
    }],
    "floor4": [{
        "apart": "401",
        "name": "Craig D"
    }, {
        "apart": "402",
        "name": "Ann"
    }, {
        "apart": "403",
        "name": "Al Mia"
    }]
}
```

The table below is just a visual aid.

```
Apartment 1   |   Name   |   Apartment 2   |   Name   |   Apartment 3   |   Name
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
201           | George   |   -             |   -      |   -             |   -   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
301           | Mary     |   302           |   Lucy   |   -             |   -   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
401           | Craig D  |   402           |   Ann    |   403           |   Al Mia
```

I have a very long code with lots of arrays within arrays, but I think it can be done in a cleaner way.

Comment: Do you have any code, did you have a particular problem doing it?

Comment: You mean you want to create a `<table>` in HTML and populate it with 'rows' from the string?

Comment: That variable isn't even valid javascript

Comment: @charlietfl, I've removed the variable declaration. The text above is what I get from a txt file. What I need is to create 3 different objects. The first object should be: 
`{"apartment": "201", name: "George"}`
the second one: 
`{"apartment": "301", name: "Mary"}
 {"apartment": "302", name: "Lucy"}`
and the third one: 
`{"apartment": "401", name: "Craig D"}
 {"apartment": "402", name: "Ann"}
 {"apartment": "403", name: "Al Mia"}`

Comment: Do you want to create the table, or do you want to convert the text to an object or both?

Comment: @JonSG, Only conver to objects. The table was to visually explain the idea. I'll edit the question

Comment: Now after a couple of edits... again a subquestion: Where do you get those `floor2, 3, 4` from?

Comment: Does that string contain any special characters, like carriage return or newline?

Comment: @Xotic750, it does contain newlines.

Comment: Can you post your current text to object transformation code?

Comment: Do either of these answers address solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am quite fond of **reduce**.  This should get you going.  I have assumed that the *floor* can be derived from the position in the data as there does not seem to be a better source.

```js
var text = "\"201 George /  / \"\n\"301 Mary / 302 Lucy / \"\n\"401 Craig Da / 402 Ann / 403 Al Mia\"";

var floors = text.split("\n");
var buildingData = floors.reduce(function(floorAcc, floor, floorIndex){
  // get rid of the odd quotes.
  floor = floor.slice(1, -1);

  var units = floor.split("/");
  floorAcc["floor" + (floorIndex + 2)] = units.reduce(function(unitAcc, unit){
    var parts = unit.trim().split(" ");
    if (parts[0].trim() === ""){ return unitAcc; }

    unitAcc.push({"apartment" : parts[0], "name" : parts.slice(1).join(" ")});
    return unitAcc;
  }, []);

  return floorAcc;
}, {});

console.log(buildingData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example in ES6

```js
function customTransform(text) {
  const myData = {};
  const props = ['apart', 'name'];
  const rx = /“([\s\S]+?)”/g;
  let match = rx.exec(text);
  while (match) {
    const tenants = match.pop().split('/').map(m => m.trim()).filter(Boolean);
    if (tenants.length) {
      let floor = tenants[0].charAt(0);
      if (/^\d$/.test(floor)) {
        floor = `floor${floor}`;
        myData[floor] = [];
        for (let tenant of tenants) {
          tenant = tenant.match(/^(\d{3})\s*([\s\S]*)$/);
          if (tenant) {
            tenant.shift();
            myData[floor].push(props.reduce((p, x) => {
              p[x] = tenant.shift();
              return p;
            }, {}));
          }
        }
        myData[floor].sort((a, b) => a.apart.localeCompare(b.apart));
      }
    }
    match = rx.exec(text);
  }
  return myData;
}

let text = '“201 George /  / ” \
“301 Mary / 302 Lucy / ” \
“401 Craig Da / 402 Ann / 403 Al Mia”';
console.log(customTransform(text));
text = '“ / 202 George / ” \
“ / 302 Mary / 303 Lucy ” \
“402 Craig Da / 403 Ann / 401 Al Mia”';
console.log(customTransform(text));
text = '“201 George /  / ”\n“301 Mary / 302 Lucy / ”\n“401 Craig Da / 402 Ann / 403 Al Mia”';
console.log(customTransform(text));
```